# Ruby on rails based CMS for personal website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, content-management-system

I am looking out for advise on best suitable Ruby on rails CMS for my personal web site. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Google "rails cms comparison". Lots of hits, including previous stackoverflow.com questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rails-world there are two big CMS: [Radiant](http://radiantcms.org/) and [RefineryCMS](http://refinerycms.com).

They compare as follows:

- Radiant:

  - runs on rails 2.3.x
  - is a complete standalone application: cannot integrate into an existing app
  - has a lot of plugins
  - is very skinnable
  - feels like a real CMS (cfr. drupal)
  - uses prototype
  - is proven technology, with a big user-base and a lot of plugins/extensions
- Refinery:

  - runs on top of rails 3
  - is much more railsey, you can add it to your own application
  - is skinnable as a standard rails-application, so not as easy as Radiant
  - uses jquery
  - is fairly new

There also is another cms option, one i have only recently discovered: [Locomotive CMS](http://www.locomotivecms.com/):

- also fairly new, not sure about the userbase
- works on top of rails3
- looks very slick, very ajaxey
- deploys on top of heroku, amazon s3
- uses mongo as db (no other option?)

Unfortunately i do not know more about it, except it seems a valid and interesting candidate to check out.

So if you want to go for proven technology, check out Radiant. It is a bit unfortunate they are still on rails 2.3.x. So for my own site I would check out RefineryCMS or LocomotiveCMS, where at the moment I seem to want to try out the latter :)

Disclaimer: I run my own blog on Wordpress :)

Answer (score 0):

[RadiantCMS](http://www.radiantcms.org) is one of the big ones, and pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

If need or want to use ruby on rails because of some special reason, you can use [Radiant CMS](http://radiantcms.org/). If not, use [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) or any other CMS, they've a bigger user base and a much bigger set of plugins.

Answer (score 0):

RadiantCMS and RefineryCMS are probably the two most widely used but If all you need is a standard easy-to-edit website then there is no reason to fence yourself in a CMS built on rails. With wordpress most of the thinking and coding has been done already whereas with rails you'll have a much steeper learning curve. MTC

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ruby on rails cms present. CMS makes the work a lot easier. I will discuss with you regarding top 5 cms.

**Radiant CMS** :

An open source content management system, Radiant is a Ruby on Rails built system designed for SMEs. It is a no-frills CMS to manage web pages. With minimal admin interface and only three components – Pages, Snippets, and Layouts. The CMS is not feature rich and it doesn’t have complicated themes, access controls and checkboxes.  Radiant CMS can manage pages and styles, and upload files. Pages can be created using plain HTML, Textile or Markdown, among others and hierarchy can be given to pages such that children pages come under parent pages. If certain parts of the content needs to be used several times, it could be saved as ‘Snippets’ to save time and efforts. The Design section of the Radiant CMS can be used to organize the complete look and feel of a website, harnessing the four parts of this elements from Layouts, Snippets, Stylesheets and Javascripts. Radiant CMS also supports custom text filters and page caching and there are various native language packs available from English, German, Russian, Italian, Dutch, French and Japanese.

**Camaleon CMS :**

Camaleon-cms is an advanced and dynamic semantic personal publishing CMS built on Ruby on Rails. Allowing to manage a website from anyplace with just an internet connection, Camaleon CMS is modular, cost-effective and scalable. Camaleon-cms is a feature-packed, established and well-coded powerful platform focused on aesthetics, web standards and usability. To read more on this cms, visit our Cameleon CMS Article.

**Slate CMS :**

Slate is a CMS built on Ruby on Rails and focuses on rapid development of traditional style websites produced by WVU Web Services. It has a multi-site support and has four system defined roles for limiting user access with MasterID integration. Slate content management system can supply custom ‘permalinks’ when creating pages for shorter URLs. It provides the drag-and-drop facility to users while breaking the pages into editable regions. This amazing CMS, has the ability to browse site in edit view

**Locomotive CMS :**
Locomotive CMS is built to focus on front-end technology, standard development process and quick learning for non-tech users. This CMS lets your tech team work locally like any other web project and they can deploy the site any time and keep the track of codes. This CMS is very user friendly for non-technical users too as the content can be edited directly underline with just a switch to editing mode. It is even user friendly for designer as the designs can be edited and changed easily.

[Read full article here](http://www.railscarma.com/blog/technical-articles/5-best-ruby-on-rails-content-management-systems-cms/).